# Use send grid in golang?

Tags: go, sendgrid

I use sendgrid to send mail in golang. Although status code return 202, email don't send. Can someone help me?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    sendgrid "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go"
    "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go/helpers/mail"
)

func main() {
    from := mail.NewEmail("Example User", "test@example.com")
    subject := "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
    to := mail.NewEmail("Example User", "trungduc08trungduc08@gmail.com")
    plainTextContent := "and easy to do anywhere, even with Go"
    htmlContent := "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Go</strong>"
    message := mail.NewSingleEmail(from, subject, to, plainTextContent, htmlContent)
    client := sendgrid.NewSendClient("my api-key")
    response, err := client.Send(message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("err:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("statusCode: ", response.StatusCode)
        fmt.Println("body: ", response.Body)
        fmt.Println("headers: ", response.Headers)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post the output

Comment: Did you try checking in the SendGrid activity logs?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have set up a SendGrid account, if not, I would start there as it has step by step instructions on how to generate a API key and test that your email has been sent by SendGrid.

Your issue is on this line (the code above looks to be pulled directly from SendGrid's example unmodified)

```
from := mail.NewEmail("Example User", "test@example.com")
```

The email address *must* be a valid email address that you control.

See https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/go for more details on how to get started.

If the above doesn't work it may also need to be validated/verified by SendGrid (you would have received a verification email when you nominated an email address for sending emails under Marketing > Marketing Campaigns > Senders > Create New Sender in your SendGrid account) before you can send emails using that email address.